# How to enable submit button only if all drop downs inside a while loop are not null

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in my webpage that puts 'n' rows with a dropdown in each of them.  Is there a way to enable submit button only if all the dropdowns contain a value (ie) the button should not be enabled even if one dropdown is empty. Also, i want the submit button to be disabled after the first click.

i've tried the following code but doesn't work.

```
$rowIndex = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
<form>
    <div>
        <select name = error_type id='error_type$rowIndex' class='picker'>
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value=2_Stage_Error>2_Stage_Error</option>
            <option value=BG_Error>BG_Error</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    $rowIndex++;
    }
    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' id='submit' onclick=report_submit()disabled
            = true />
</form>
```

JS

```
  <script type= "text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.picker').on('change', function() {
    var $sels = $('.picker option:selected[value=""]');
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", $sels.length > 0);
  }).change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, use `jQuery.prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dvphbf5f/1/

Comment: did you intentionally put your while loop outside the form?

Comment: @NewbeeDev yes. I'm pulling data from a database based on certain filters and i would add some data through the dropdown and insert it into another table

Comment: @Rayon thanks for the fiddle, but that code works for normal seperate dropdowns, when i put the class as <select name=error_type class='picker'> (ie) inside a while loop, the button does not get enabled

Comment: Check the `HTML` which is being create in `loop`, make sure it is valid...

Answer (score 0):

Use `required` on the select statement it specifies the user is required to select a value before submitting the form.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required

Answer (score 0):

first of all make the button disabled. the submit button i mean. 
then try this:

```
function checkAllHasValue(){
   $(".picker").each(function(){
   var elem = $(this);
   if(elem.val()+"" == "undefined"){
     return false;
   }

})
  return true;
}

$(".picker").on("change",function(){
   if(checkAllHasValue){
     $("submitbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
   }

})
```